# Was Odin the reason Thanos never collected the stones personally?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Once Odin died in the *Marvel Cinematic Universe* Thanos personally started collecting the stones. Does that mean he was no match for Odin? Or was it just right timing?

Comment: Don't forget The Ancient One and Ego.

Comment: Oh yeah .. True.

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89230/where-was-thanos-before-the-events-of-avengers-infinity-war

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Was Odin the reason Thanos never collected the stones personally?

Not really, no. Thanos' hunt for Infinity Stones has started in 2012 in *The Avengers*. Remember, Thanos sends Loki to get Tessaract (i.e. Space Stone) by giving a scepter that contained the Mind Stone. Eventually, Loki gets defeated and the Tessaract was kept in Asgard's vault.

In the post-credits of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Thanos is shown saying,

> Fine. I'll do it myself.

So, he was tired of failure of whoever he sends to retrieve Infinity Stones. Therefore, he decided to collect them by himself.

Moreover, it is not stated in movies nor there are official words till now regarding if Thanos is no match for Odin. We haven't seen them fighting each other. Neither it is stated that he was only waiting for certain people to die before starting collecting them. You will find many fan theories, but there is no official words regarding this.

> Or just it was right timing?

So, it was just a coincidence.

Comment: I wouldn't neglect the timing to fast. AoU is 2 years before Ragnarok where Thanos "meets" with Thor and that is just (afair 2 weeks) after he got the first stone. So either he needed so much time to find the first stone and then suddenly knows where to find the other, or it was a different reason (such as some powerfull beeings out of the way)

Comment: The AoU scene shows Thanos putting on the Gauntlet. In IW it had only recently been created, not two years previously.

Comment: In _Thor: Ragnarok_ Odin stated that `Thor is more powerful than Odin`. Thor is still alive when Thanos is collecting the stones, moreover, he collected one from him.

Comment: @Clayn Also remember that he had to collect all the stones. Giving that "no one knows where the soul stone is", he had to wait untill he knew all the stones whereabouts, which happened to be right after he captured Gomora's sister.

Comment: I think the "I'll do it myself" was specifically referring to Ronan not only failing to collect the power stone but attempting to steal it for himself.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Whatever Odin says, he's so much stronger than Thor that he could turn him into a regular person without any visible effort (first Thor movie).

Comment: @SergeSeredenko That was newbie Thor. He has evolved tremendously since then. By the time Thanos started collecting the stones, I'd say Thor is as much powerfull as Odin, if not more.

Comment: Power in this franchise is measured by the "size of the hammer", particularly if properly aimed to the head.

Comment: @OrangeDog You can't rely on movie stingers for timing.  The second one for _Ant-Man_ occurs during _Civil War_, which is supposed to be set a year later.

Answer (score 8):

Thanos' motivation to start collecting the Infinity Stones himself, as shown at the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, is that he's grown tired of his subordinates' failures to collect them:

> THANOS: Fine, I'll do it myself.

The fact that Odin happened to die at around that time is sheer coincidence. I don't believe there's any indication in the MCU that Thanos even knows who Odin *is*, let alone that he was hanging back out of fear of Odin.

Comment: I think Thanos know who Odin is, as he said he was also cursed with knowledge to Stark. I think he knew, but didn't cared much about Odin, IMO